# SVG background in expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, expo

how can I make my SVG file as a background image of my component? I already used react-native-svg.

```
<Container style={{ marginVertical: 150, margin: 20 }}>

        <Svg width="360" height="640" fill="none">
            <Path
                d="M0 0h360v640H0z"
                fill="red"
            />
        </Svg>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View>
    <Svg width="360" height="640" fill="none" style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
        <Path
            d="M0 0h360v640H0z"
            fill="red"
        />
    </Svg>
    {children}
  </View>
```

Maybe this code will work since the implementation of [ImageBackground](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js) is like this. The svg is in the background and all children (components) will be in the foreground.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how can I remove the fill attribute and just use my svg file?

Comment: I think it's a problem with your path component. I simply see a rectangle when I use your path with the specific d prop

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for your use case, save your svg to a file then you can set it as the css `background-image: url(<file>.svg);` of your component. You can even ref subcomponents of the svg file, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()

Comment: The css code background-url isn't supported by react-native.